# SKAction rotateToAngle has no duration

Tags: objective-c, rotation, skspritenode, skaction

**It's instantly rotating my SKSpriteNode to it's destination**

```
        [self addChild:lastCardAnimated];

        float angle = M_PI/0;

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [lastCardAnimated runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:5]];
        });
```

However, the rotation is immediate, so it doesn't interpolate it's way there. It arrives at the end instantly.

Does anyone see why my code would present that issue? ( I only added to dispatch after to make sure it was appearing, as it wasn't showing without it as it was instantly being rotated.

edit, thought i'd add this is being ran from inside a for loop.

EDIT:

also tried this

```
    SKNode *animateNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"animatedLastCards"];

    float angle = M_PI/0;

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [animateNode runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:5]];
    });
```

outside of the loop. Still, instant.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the angle to Zero made it work, however I'm not sure why.